# mongoose conditional query returns unexpected doc

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

**Records in User Collection:**

```
[
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "617849bc35a25323c48cdd58",
    "email": "mockEmail",
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-26T18:32:28.241Z"
  },
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "617849bc35a25323c48cdd5b",
    "email": "mockEmail2",
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-26T18:32:28.297Z"
  }
]
```

**Code been executed:**

```
await User.find({email:"mockEmail",tag:"mockTag"}).exec();
```

**Result:**

The first doc is returned

**Expected behavior:**

No document should be returned since both documents have no `tag`.

**I tried to:**

1. Run this script on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/) and got the expected result(no document found)
2. Use $and operator even though I think this is default behavior by mongoose

```
await User.find({$and:[{email:"mockEmail"},{tag:"mockTag"}]}).exec();
```

still returned the first doc.

**Package Version:**

mongoose: 6.0.6

@types/node: 16.9.1

Comment: what about: `await User.find({$and:[{email:"mockEmail"},{tag: { $exists: true, $in: ["mockTag"] } }]})`

Comment: @giankotarola Thank you very much for your suggestion, still got one doc returned unexpectedly, guess I need to check if there is something wrong somewhere else